# Group array type columns in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe column that has the structure below:

```
[{id:1, value:"a"},
 {id: 2, value: "b"},
 {id: 1, value: "c"}
]
```

I want to convert it to get the result below optimally and without using a UDF if possible

```
[{id: 1, value:["a","b"]},
 {id: 2, value: "b"}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this out :

```
df2 = sqlContext.read.json(sc.parallelize([{'id':1, 'value':"a"},
 {'id': 2, 'value': "b"},
 {'id': 1, 'value': "c"}
]))

df2.show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  1|    a|
|  2|    b|
|  1|    c|
+---+-----+
```

You can aggregate based on ID and then collect list of the values.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df2.groupBy('id').agg(F.collect_list('value')).show()

+---+-------------------+
| id|collect_list(value)|
+---+-------------------+
|  1|             [a, c]|
|  2|                [b]|
+---+-------------------+
```